# How to set classpath for sqlmapconfig.xml in maven project

Tags: java, sql, maven, intellij-idea, ibatis

I started learn ibatis framework. I am using Intellij and Maven. But there are some problems. My main java class cannot find my sql config xml:
[image]

In which directory should be my SqlMapConfig.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used mybatis, but from the documentation it looks like you need to add the XML to a package, then reference the path in your main method.

http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html

```
String resource = "org/mybatis/builder/mybatis-config.xml";
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
SqlSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder();
SqlSessionFactory factory = builder.build(inputStream);
```

`org/mybatis/builder/mybatis-config.xml` is in `src/main/java/`

Comment: Honestly, the config should go into the `src/main/resources`